# PHP - why equal string are not equal with NumberFormatter

Tags: php, string, equality, numberformatter

Why are below code echos not equal even if both strings are equal?

```
$number = 1234567.89;
$expected = 'GBP 1,234,567.89';

$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en_AU@currency=GBP', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$currency = $fmt->formatCurrency($number, 'GBP');

echo "$expected = $currency ?" . PHP_EOL;
echo $expected == $currency ? 'equals' : "not equal";
```

**Output**

```
GBP 1,234,567.89 = GBP 1,234,567.89 ?
not equal
```

Any help will be really helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because `$expected` variable has a whitespace after "GBP"

```
$expected = 'GBP 1,234,567.89';
```

does not equal to **'GBP1,234,567.89';**

actually you can debug them;

```
echo $expected;
echo "<br>";
echo $currency;
```

Comment: Hey, I just found it out see the answer I added, it was because of a special character. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay trying a few things I got the answer. The $exoected and $currency has a different encoding.

```
print_r([mb_detect_encoding($expected), mb_detect_encoding($currency)]);

Array
(
    [0] => ASCII
    [1] => UTF-8
)
```

The space character in $currency is 194 ASCII number whereas space character in $expected is 32

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/', $number, $matches)) {
    print_r(ord($matches[0]));
    print_r(ord(' '));
}
```

Hope this helps someone who scratching their head

Comment: It's likely actually `194 160` (can't be looking at single byte values only, when working with UTF-8), which would be a non-breaking space. And it makes sense that the formatter would use one in this location, because you usually don't want the `GBP` shown at the end of a line of text, and have the `1,234,567.89` break into the next one.